# How to remove or edit surrounding white space?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

How can I remove all the white spaces in the surrounding or edit it? I mean how to make the white spaces less thicker? ____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

```css
  *,
    *:after,
    *:before {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial;
    }


    ul {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
      list-style: none;
      width: 955px;
      height: 450px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      overflow: hidden;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px;
      
      
    }

    li {
      position: relative;
      width: 190px;
      height: 450px;
      float: left;
      border-left: 1px solid white;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
      transition: all 0.7s;
      box-shadow: -2px 0 10px 2px;
      border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }

    ul li:first-child {
      border: none;
    }

    span {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 50%;
      color: white;
      white-space: nowrap;
      padding: 20px;
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        left,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
      ); /* FF3.6+ */
      background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)),
        color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))
      ); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
        left,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
      ); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(
        left,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
      ); /* Opera 11.10+ */
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(
        left,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
      ); /* IE10+ */
      background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 0%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
      ); /* W3C */
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }

    img {
      width: 800px;
      height: 450px;
    }

    ul:hover li {
      width: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
      
    }

    ul li:hover {
      width: 750px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
      <title>Currency Notes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="country-flags">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>MYR</span>
        <img src='images/malay.png' /></li>
      
      <li>
        <span>RMB</span>
        <img src='images/china-flag-medium.jpg' /></li>
      
      <li>
        <span>USD</span>
        <img src='images/united-states-of-america-flag-medium.jpg' /></li>
      
      <li>
        <span>SGD</span>
        <img src='images/singapore-flag-medium.jpg' />
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <span>HKD</span>
        <img src='images/new HK.jpg' />
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: You can attach an image to visualize the problem, furthermore, your question is too broad.

Comment: I've added a picture, that's how I want it to be.  How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
body {
          padding: 100px;
         }

ul {
          position: absolute;
          display: flex;
          align-content: center;
          justify-content: center;
          list-style: none;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          border-radius: 3px;
          overflow: hidden;
          box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px;
        }

li {
      position: relative;
      width: 190px;
      height: 75%;
      float: left;
      border-left: 1px solid white;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
      transition: all 0.7s;
      box-shadow: -2px 0 10px 2px;
      border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: No it did not work

Comment: @ryan Please try now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).